# JavaScript and forward slashes in strings

Tags: javascript

What is the real reason that we must escape a forward slash in a JavaScript string, and also why must we escape string/no string in XHTML.  A lot of tutorials just brush over this issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What is the real reason that we must escape a forward slash in a JavaScript string

In an HTML 4 document, the sequence `</` inside an element defined as containing CDATA (such as script) is an end tag and will end the element (with an error if it is not `</script>`.

As far as JS is concerned `/` and `\/` are identical inside a string. As far as HTML is concerned `</` starts an end tag but `<\/` does not.

> , and also why must we escape string/no string in XHTML.

XHTML doesn't provide a method of specifying that an element intrinsically contains CDATA, so you need to explicitly handle characters which would otherwise have special meaning (`<`, `&`, etc). Wrapping the contents of the element with CDATA markers is the easiest way to achieve this.

Comment: So we never have to escape a single forward slash, only a </ ? whether it is XHTML inside a string or outside a string? Thanks :-)

Comment: In other words in XHTML when must we escape a forward slash?

Comment: In "normal" XHTML (which nobody uses), never. In HTML-compatible XHTML (which everybody who wants IE 8 and lower to be supported uses), the same places as in HTML.

Comment: So, @rubixibuc, to recap, and make it clear: "So we never have to escape a single forward slash, only a </ ?". Correct.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to escape `/` in a JavaScript string, just `\`, because if you don't, then the string `yes\no` will inadvertently be transformed into `yes<newline>o`. Escaping the `\` will prevent that.

Also, if you don't escape `&` in a URL, then whatever comes after it will be considered a new parameter. For example, `a=Q&A` will mean "the parameter `a` has the value "`Q`" and there's also a parameter `A`" instead of "the parameter `a` has the value "`Q&A`"". The correct way of escaping that would be `a=Q%26A`.

Comment: Why would you write `yes\no` for the prompt?

Comment: @Paŭlo, you probably wouldn't, that's the best example of unintended use I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

The slash is needed to prevent browsers, particularly older ones, to erroneously interpret the forward slash as a closing JavaScript marker.

Comment: There is nothing erroneous about it.

Comment: @Quentin, of course, it's erroneous. While in a string mode, the special for the interpreter characters are just characters...