# String literal causes "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" in Chrome, Firefox

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, string-literals

Here's the entire document that causes the error in Firefox and Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var strs = [], scripts = ['harbl.js'], s = 0;
        strs.push('<script src="' + scripts[s] + '"></script>');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>buh...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cryptoquick/J4zZT/

The error I get is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

This has me really puzzled.

Comment: @Sednus what is the point of that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `</script>` literal is parsed by the browser as it's not aware of the context when traversing your code. You have to escape it like so : `<\/script>`. It's a known problem.

Comment: Thanks bro! I'll acknowledge your answer in... 10 minutes. :)

Answer (score 3):

Change it to:

```
strs.push('<script src="' + scripts[s] + '"></s' + 'cript>');
```

Comment: Heh, that's one way to do it... :)

Comment: I forget why, but this is how I saw it done a loooooong time ago. Didn't know about the answer from @TimLamballais so that's good to know.

Comment: Yeah I guess this is a solution that was floating around the net a long time ago, I've seen it before in legacy code.

Answer (score -1):

Front Slash `'/'` is considered as special character . It's the cause for the error .

```
strs.push('<script src="' + scripts[s] + '"><\/script>');
```

Please read this post for more information  [JavaScript and forward slashes in strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117886/two-part-question-on-javascript-forward-slash) .