# Undetermined String Literal Error with DIV-Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, literals

I have a Javascript / JQuery problem.

I get unterminated string literal when I use this code:

```
var newInfo = '<div><span class="testClass"><a title="edit" href="'+link+'">'+oldVal+'</a></span></div>';
```

If I delete the `</div>` 
tag, it works... But I need this.
I am totally out of ideas.

Maybe you can help, thanks.

Comment: What do you have in oldVal? Perhaps is there one `</div>`...

Comment: Is it something to do with your values for link or oldVal?

Comment: Where (as in IDE, Browser console, Output, etc) are you getting this error?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227552/common-sources-of-unterminated-string-literal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
var newInfo = '<di'+'v><span class="testClass"><a title="edit" href="'+link+'">'+oldVal+'</a></span></di'+'v>';
```

Seperating the div tags helped me on a similar problem

Comment: Oh my god, why? Thanks that solves the problem... Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Escape your slashes.

```
var newInfo = '<div><span class="testClass"><a title="edit" href="' + link + '">' + oldVal + '<\/a><\/span><\/div>';
```

You could also just build your html as actual DOM elements instead of a string (which avoids a lot of pitfalls, including this one).

```
var div = $('<div />'),
    span = $('<span />').addClass('testClass'),
    a = $('<a />').text(oldVal).attr({
        "href": link,
        "title": "edit"
    }),
    newInfo = div.append(span.append(a));
```

Comment: Thanks, that works just fine too.. But I don't understand why.

Comment: @rattlex: `/` can have a special meaning in a lot of JavaScript strings, especially when you're passing it to `innerHTML` or a regex, or if it's in a JSON string. In 'innerHTML`, `/` generally only has a special meaning when immediately preceded by '<', so `</` in particular needs to be escaped (`<\/`). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117886/two-part-question-on-javascript-forward-slash, http://www.irt.org/articles/js169/#4.7, or https://www.google.com/search?q=why+escape+forward+slash+in+javascript+string for more details.